# Accept "Apple Pay" from your app using NFC

Tags: ios, nfc

I have a retail solution (an iOS point of sale app) to which I need to integrate "Apple Pay". How do I make it possible to accept payment details via NFC?. i.e. the customer will pay using "Apple Pay" and the cashier who is using my app should be able to process it.

Comment: You wait for Apple to make Pay Kit available in the future.

Comment: Also see [Getting Started with Apple Pay](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/Getting-Started-with-Apple-Pay.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NFC portion is not an in-app feature, it is a feature between the device and an NFC terminal. The software portion of Apple Pay allows users to make online purchases with their stored credit card, and does not require NFC.

See [Getting Started with Apple Pay](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/Getting-Started-with-Apple-Pay.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was actually looking whether I could build an app which could accept (not pay) payments done via Apple pay. Guess that is not possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

'Apple Pay' - PassKit framework provides APIs for Apple Pay. However, as per the information on Apple Press "*Apple Pay APIs will be available to developers in iOS 8 so they can enable purchasing physical goods within their apps on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus*" - which means they are currently not exposed to developers.

Our understanding is that it will be available from Oct 20 onward.

Regarding on the integration - once the APIs are integrated, the user's credit card will be charged directly - and it is similar to the way Credit Card payments are being handled now, except for the fact that - you pay with your mobile with your touchID as security. Users can pay for physical goods and services including apparel, electronics, health and beauty products, tickets and more with Touch ID. Checkout can happen with a single touch, so there’s no need to manually fill out lengthy account forms or repeatedly type in shipping and billing information, and card details are kept private and are not shared with the online merchant.

For more details visit - https://www.apple.com/pr/library/2014/09/09Apple-Announces-Apple-Pay.html and http://www.macrumors.com/roundup/apple-pay/